# Core dump following g++ compilation + link with jni and subsequent execution of application using C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, linker, java-native-interface, invocation

I require to execute some arbitrary Java code from within C++. I am utilizing the JNI for this but have encountered an issue. The C++ file compiles fine, however upon execution the following is produced:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6f90ffb, pid=10063, tid=3062122240
>
> JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode linux-x86 )
>   Problematic frame:
>   V  [libjvm.so+0x440ffb]  JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg::JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg(_jmethodID*, char*)+0x1b
>
> Core dump written. Default location: /home/alex/candjava/core or core.10063
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /home/alex/candjava/hs_err_pid10063.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>     http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

The compilation command:

`g++ sample.cpp -o app -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux -I $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/client -L$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/client -ljvm -Wno-write-strings`

where `$JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`

The java source:

```
public class Main{

public void test(){
    System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```

The C++ source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-D java.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    /* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
     * pointer in env */
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    delete options;
    /* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
    /* We are done. */
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();

}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: That's a pretty odd class path.

Comment: This option shouldn't have a space in it and it should point to the location of some Java classes `"-D java.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't checking any error returns from the JNI functions. You need to check for errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559059/jni-env-getstaticmethodid-crashed-program

I used the code outlined in that link to solve my issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
```

says your function is void and you have integer as argument.
but you are not sending any integer argument 
it must be as follows

```
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "()V");
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some obvious errors in your source code.

1. the test method in the Main class should be static
2. the test parameter should be int
3. the java.class.path parameter is ridiculous

I also have the third problem. change the option `-Djava.class.path=/Path-to-your-class-file-directory` will be ok. (Mine is `"-Djava.class.path=."`)